# Conditional replace and delete column

Tags: r, if-statement, dataframe

I have a dataframe like so:

```
replaceanddropcolumn <- data.frame("avariable"=10,
                                   "bvariable"=5,
                                   "cvariable"=2)

  avariable bvariable cvariable
1        10         5         2
```

I want to use the grep function to find if `cvariable` exists in the dataframe, then replace `cvariable` with `bvariable`, and finally delete `cvariable` from the dataframe. So the final output would look like this:

```
replaceanddropcolumn[["bvariable"]] <- replaceanddropcolumn[["cvariable"]]
replaceanddropcolumn[["cvariable"]] <- NULL

  avariable bvariable
1        10         2
```

The reason I need the if statement is that I want to keep the original dataframe if `cvariable` does not exist eg. I have a dataframe like this:

```
replaceanddropcolumn <- data.frame("avariable"=10,
                                   "bvariable"=5,
                                   "dvariable"=14)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can design a function with `if-else` statement to complete this task.

```
replace_fun <- function(df, target_column, replace_column){
  if (target_column %in% colnames(df)){
    df[[replace_column]] <- df[[target_column]]
    df[[target_column]] <- NULL
  }
  return(df)
}
```

The first argument of `replace_fun` is the data frame. The second argument is the target column. The third argument is the column for replacement.

#### Test the function

```
replaceanddropcolumn1 <- data.frame("avariable"=10,
                                   "bvariable"=5,
                                   "cvariable"=2)

replaceanddropcolumn2 <- data.frame("avariable"=10,
                                   "bvariable"=5,
                                   "dvariable"=14)

replace_fun(replaceanddropcolumn1, "cvariable", "bvariable")

#   avariable bvariable
# 1        10         2

replace_fun(replaceanddropcolumn2, "cvariable", "bvariable")
#   avariable bvariable dvariable
# 1        10         5        14
```